# Displaying Decimal Number within PyQt QLCDNumber

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am creating a beam profiler GUI using PyQt5 and am having trouble with the `QLCDNumber` widget. I cannot figure out how to have the `QLCDNumber` display decimals. I need the widget to display a calculate value which will be smaller than one, but now it seems to be automatically rounding to the nearest integer and will display a 0. I repeated the process, with the number it displays now being equal to 6.55 and it rounds up and displays 7. I have been trying to use the `setSmallDecimalPoint` function but am not sure how to use it correctly.
The relevant code is as follows:

```
self.lcdNumber_div = QtWidgets.QLCDNumber(self)
self.lcdNumber_div.setSmallDecimalPoint(1)
div=6.55
self.lcdNumber_div.display(div)
```

This above code causes the QLCD to display 6.
How can I have the QLCD widget display 6.55 rather than 7?
Furthermore, can I use the QLCD widget to display a number less than 0, such as 0.0045?

Comment: Try with `display('{:.02f}'.format(div)), but consider that QLCDNumber is an extremely old (and almost unmaintained) one that still exists only for backward compatibility. You'll probably have more luck with a custom widget or a QLabel with a custom font.

Comment: Is the QLCDNumber stretched horizontally? Perhaps that is causing the decimals not to be displayed. Please provide a [mre]

Comment: @musicamante Why do you say that it is not maintained? that there are no changes does not imply that it is not maintained but that it does not need them.

Comment: @eyllanesc You're right, wrong choice of words. The point is, it's a very old (and odd) widget for which there has never been any active interest in "updating" it to conform its behavior to more advanced requirements, consistent behavior or even Qt consistency (while "display" makes sense, it doesn't comply with the Qt standard `setProperty[Type]()`). And that's fine, I consider it a *legacy* widget that still has reason to exist, but some easily achievable implementation could have been added, including separating the display of numbers and an easier way to show float digits.

Comment: @musicamante I don't see anything wrong, the display method supports string, int and double so floating point should work. Have you tried the code? I have typically encountered problems with display if qlayouts are not used as it does not expand horizontally when displaying decimals and I think that is the case: The OP has used QtDesigner to position the widget giving it a small width so the decimals are hidden.

Comment: @eyllanesc I'm not saying that it doesn't work. But almost every time I decided to give it a try, I ended up with a custom widget instead, except for *extremely* simplistic situations. I see it similar to QDial, which (also for other similar reasons) is very limited and oddly supported with very few attention especially for certain styles. And I get it: it's rarely used, and due to its nature, trying to extend it isn't worth it, as that would introduce more issues than benefits. I'm just pointing out that it's old and (comprehensibly) there's no intention to "update" it to more *modern* needs.

Comment: @musicamante I think that comment is unnecessarily distracting, the OP's point is not to discuss whether the widget is modern or not, but rather that it doesn't work for him for a trivial case that should work. It is better to focus on the problem. Another thing would be if it were a very special case (which perhaps were your requirements) where the solution would be to propose custom widgets.

Comment: It seems you have [digitCount](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlcdnumber.html#digitCount) set to `1`. To display both `6.55` and `0.0045` correctly, you must call `self.lcdNumber_div.setDigitCount(6)`, and then reset the current display value.